# merge two arrays (keys and values) into an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

Is there a common Javascript/Coffeescript-specific idiom I can use to accomplish this? Mainly out of curiosity.

I have two arrays, one consisting of the desired keys and the other one consisting of the desired values, and I want to merge this in to an object.

```
keys = ['one', 'two', 'three']
values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. Object members can be accessed in an array-like syntax, but they are still objects.

Comment: @nikc: Thanks, I realize that. But given the context I felt like 'associative array' would've communicated what I was going for in less words.

Comment: @Jorge - just call it an object, 'cos that's what javascript has. Less to type too. ;-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```js
var r = {},
    i,
    keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    values = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    r[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

console.log(r);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great answer but is there a way to keep the duplicates?

Comment: @rashadb No. Objects can not have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 7):

```
keys = ['one', 'two', 'three']
values = ['a', 'b', 'c']

d = {}

for i, index in keys
    d[i] = values[index]
```

Explanation:
In coffeescript you can iterate an array and get each item and its position on the array, or index.
So you can then use this index to assign keys and values to a new object.

Comment: This is what I ultimately did (though before you answered). Still, +1 for you :)

Comment: This is simple and nice, we have to be gratefull there are no nullliners, becuz the oneliners are looking ugly:)

Answer (score 6):

As long as the two arrays are the same length, you can do this:

```
var hash = {};
var keys = ['one', 'two', 'three']
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    hash[keys[i]] = values[i];

console.log(hash['one'])
console.log(hash.two);
```

Comment: Great answer but is there a way to keep the duplicates?

Comment: @rashadb No. Objects can not have duplicate keys.