# merge two arrays of keys and values to an object using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Given two arrays, one with keys, one with values:

```
keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']
values = ['1', '2', '3']
```

How would you convert it to an object, ***by only using underscore.js methods***?

```
{
   foo: '1', 
   bar: '2',
   qux: '3'
}
```

I'm not looking for a plain javascript answer ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921962/merge-two-arrays-keys-and-values-into-an-object)).

I'm asking this as a personal exercise. I thought underscore had a method that was doing exactly this, only to find out it doesn't, and that got me wondering if it could be done. 
I have an answer, but it involves quite a few operations. How would you do it?

Comment: The same question without underscore.js: [Merge keys array and values array into an object in JavaScript](/q/1117916/4642212).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you need to use is the [_.object](http://underscorejs.org/#object) method of underscore js.
If object method is not present in your version of underscore.js then you will have to manually add this method to it.

```js
keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']
values = ['1', '2', '3']
_.object = function(list, values) {
  if (list == null) return {};
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (values) {
      result[list[i]] = values[i];
    } else {
      result[list[i][0]] = list[i][1];
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(_.object(keys, values))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _If object method is not present in your version of underscore.js_ then **update to latest version** :)

Comment: How do you keep duplicates?

Comment: @rashadb what do you mean by duplicates? If the key is different then duplicate values in the second array will appear as values in distinct key-value pairs. If there're duplicates in the first array then there's no way you can retain them since an object can not have two or more keys with the same name. Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I had two arrays:  ["2KE8eiJYBu", "W5gWjvSUCp", "aFqSkbkfgp", "kTC0RwDalJ", "kTC0RwDalJ", "yCDDEWoiwM", "yCDDEWoiwM"]

and 

[Array[16], Array[16], Array[16], Array[16], Array[16], Array[16], Array[16]]

where i wanted to make the strings keys for each array in sequence. After too much struggle I used underscore for my solution starting with: "act"
[child, child, child, child, child, child, child]

Comment: var grouped = _.groupBy(_.zip(_.pluck(_.map(_.map(act, function(n){return _.pluck(n, "user")}), function(a){return _.first(a)}),"id"), _.map(_.map(act, function(n){return _.pluck(n, "aValue")}), function(a){return _.first(a)})), function(n){return n[0]});

where each of the act 'child' has an aValue key which is an array of objects and a user key which is an object made of several key value pairs.

Comment: I know, could it be more convoluted, right? I broke this up to several mini functions but it wouldn't fit in the space provided so there it is all together.

Answer (score 51):

I know you asked for Underscore.js solutions, but you don't need it for this. Here's a oneliner using ES7 object spread operator and dynamic keys.

```
keys.reduce((obj, k, i) => ({...obj, [k]: values[i] }), {})
```

Comment: OP clearly stated to use underscore.js to solve this problem

Comment: @RizkiDPrast but many more people will read this and consider more options.  The question is old.

Comment: simplified: `keys.reduce((acc, k, i) => (acc[k] = values[i], acc), {})` I like the idea of using reduce, but you don't need to re-create the outer object every iteration.

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 40):

Using ES6:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3],
    names = ["John", "Mike", "Colin"];

let a = Object.assign({}, ...numbers.map((n, index) => ({[n]: names[index]})))

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Why hasn't this been up voted more? Nice work, @TudorMorar

Answer (score 15):

Given that this is 4 years old, and Lodash has more or less taken the place of Underscore, I thought I would share this solution using Lodash:

```
var keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'];
var values = ['1', '2', '3'];
var obj = _.zipObject( keys, values );
```

Simple and clean.

Comment: Simple, clean, and elegant. Lodash has superseded Underscore, like you mentioned, so this is clearly the canonical solution!

Answer (score 14):

How about:

```
keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'];
values = ['1', '2', '3'];
some = {};
_.each(keys,function(k,i){some[k] = values[i];});
```

To be complete: another approach could be:

```
 _.zip(['foo', 'bar', 'qux'],['1', '2', '3'])
  .map(function(v){this[v[0]]=v[1];}, some = {});
```

For the record, without underscore you could extend Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.toObj = function(values){
   values = values || this.map(function(v){return true;}); 
   var some;
   this .map(function(v){return [v,this.shift()]},values)
        .map(function(v){this[v[0]]=v[1];},some = {});
   return some; 
};
// usage
var some = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'].toObj(['1', '2', '3']);
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/DhzqM/)

Comment: Nice, better then what I came up with (`zip` then `reduce` to new object)

Comment: Hi @Cristi, added a `_.zip` and `.map` alternative

Comment: I have two arrays like keys and values that I want to put together in an object but none of the examples provided herein work. The first only returns the keys array.  The second returns undefined.

Comment: @rashadb: I'm sorry to hear that. Try fiddling around with your code in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/DhzqM/ and tell me what's going wrong

Answer (score 7):

```js
var toObj = (ks, vs) => ks.reduce((o,k,i)=> {o[k] = vs[i]; return o;}, {});

var keys=['one', 'two', 'three'],
    values = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = toObj(keys, values);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I would expect this to be the most efficient solution due to only creating one object instead of an object per key. Someone else beat you by 3 years, but they don't exist anymore, so you get the upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Cleanest is

```js
keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']
values = ['1', '2', '3']

function Arr2object(keys, vals) {
  return keys.reduce(
    function(prev, val, i) {
      prev[val] = vals[i];
      return prev;
    }, {}
  );
}

console.log(Arr2object(keys, values));
```

Or, use `_.reduce`, but if you're using underscore you already have `_.object`.

Comment: Look at @TudorMorar 's answer. It is way cleaner than this.

Comment: @JasonSebring I use that pattern myself and have given it in other answers. On the downside, it is a bit unreadable.

Comment: @torazabura  actually I agree. I have an alternate implementation that seems way more readable, minus lodash dependancy. I needed to objectize Promise.all, actually should name it differently, any suggestions? see https://gist.github.com/sebringj/454cadc7773d5fcd13eaa740b077e63f thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the zip function.

[zip function](http://underscorejs.org/#zip)

Edit:
It doesn't create an object but it does combine the array by creating a sub array

There's no function that exactly does what you want. But you can use the result of zip to create your object.

```
var arr = _.zip(['foo', 'bar', 'qux'], ['1', '2', '3']);
var i, len = arr.length;
var new_obj = [];

for(i=0; i<len; ++i)
   new_obj[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
```

Comment: `zip` is not enough, `_.zip(['foo', 'bar', 'qux'], ['1', '2', '3'])` is `[['foo, '1'], ['bar', '2'], ['qux', '3']]`

Comment: I added a code to use the return of zip to create the object. underscore doesn't have a function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, it seems there is no pure underscore way of doing it.