# make one object out of several arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have several arrays with stored information from a simple form

`var name = [a, b, c, ...];
var last = [x, y, z, ...];
var age = [1, 2, 3];`

Now it is the idea that when someone new fills in the form, and thus a new element is added to the arrays, a new object is created which holds this persons information
like:

```
function Person(name,last,age){
this.name=name;
this.last=last;
this.age=age;
}

var object1 = new Person(name[1],last[1],age[1]);
```

Obviously I don't want to manually create a new object every time, so I guess something has to be done with a for loop, but how does this generate a new name for object(i)?

I am quite new to javascript, and possibly I am overthinking things and is the answer staring me right in the face, But I really could use some help here.
Thanks a million!

Comment: Just store the resulting `Person` objects in an array ;).

Comment: If the arrays are not of the same size, the number of persons will be equal to length of the array with the fewest number of elements?  Can this be assumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different version from p.s.w.g which is good anyways, assuming that every field is always filled (every array has the same size).

```
var persons = [];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)  
  persons.push(new Person(names[i], lasts[i], ages[i]));
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
var len = Math.min(name.length, last.length, age.length),
    objects = new Array(len);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    objects[i] = new Person(name[i], last[i], age[i]);
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/4FCey/)

Comment: `objects = []` would be enough instead of `objects = new Array(len)`.

Comment: @kapa correct, but I believe setting an initial capacity is slightly more efficient.

Comment: @pswg [Depends on the browser](http://jsperf.com/big-array-initialize/2), AFAIK. And microoptimization is evil ;). But I am always ready to learn.

Comment: @kapa I believe it also depends a lot on the size of the array. See this [comparison](http://jsperf.com/big-array-initialize/8) which has an initial size of 99999, just one less.

Comment: @pswg Currently only has data from Chrome :). But of course the size of the array matters. And a lot of other things. I still say do not microoptimize.

Answer (score 0):

One liner using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) ([zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip), [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [object](http://underscorejs.org/#object)):

```
var people = _.map(_.zip(names, lasts, ages), function(p) { return _.object(['name','last','age'], p); });
```

Comment: **Note**: if you're new to JS but not to programming in general, I'd highly advise using Underscore. Also, if you don't have Underscore or would like to see an implementation of `_.object()`, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14399998/2882550

Comment: **Also**: this can be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117916/merge-keys-array-and-values-array-into-an-object-in-javascript