# javascript array sorting / array match sorted array

Tags: javascript, sorting

if i have an array of values, and an array of characters

```
var values = [31, 11, 10, 51]
var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

i then sort the values array with .sort

```
values.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); // result: [10, 11, 31, 51]
```

if i then want the chars array to be sorted to match the values array - how do i go about doing that ?

so that the result will be:

```
 // wanted result
 [10, 11, 31, 51] 
 ['c','b','a','d']
```

Comment: The answer can be found in [an older post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199051/merge-two-arrays-of-keys-and-values-to-an-object-using-underscore)

Comment: var arr = [ {value:31, chars: 'a'},
         {value:11, chars: 'b'},
         {value:10, chars: 'c'},
         {value:51, chars: 'd'}];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.value - b.value;
});

console.log(arr);