# Merge 2 arrays using 2 different keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

If you have 2 arrays

```
var number = [1, 2, 3];
var color = ['red', 'white', 'blue'];
```

How can you create an object that looks like this:

```
var combined = [
    {
        number: 1,
        color: 'red'
    },
    {
        number: 2,
        color: 'white'
    },
    {
        number: 3,
        color: 'blue'
    },
];
```

Bonus points for using underscore.js

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: seriously this is not a homework for free service..

Comment: webdev & JordanHendrix, actually doing this is extremely easy.  It's also ugly (see below).  I guess I was really just trying to ask if underscore had a method for it or if some clever combination of methods would clean up the task.  No homework here webdev.

Comment: ok JordanHendrix posted exactly the type of answer I was looking for in the comments below.  I'm sorry I didn't include a really crappy way of accomplishing it before asking for a clever way.  I need to study up on .map() because it seems to be the common deuglifier.

Comment: You all down voted the crap out of this, but go ahead and watch how useful this becomes to people in the future.  People of the future, you're welcome.

Comment: not really, there are multiple duplicates with positive votes...heres one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199051/merge-two-arrays-of-keys-and-values-to-an-object-using-underscore

Comment: That's one array as keys and one as values.  That's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using underscore,

```
var number = [1, 2, 3];
var color = ['red', 'white', 'blue'];
var combined = _.map(number, function(num, key) {
    return {
        number: num,
        color: color[key]
    }
});

console.log(combined);
```