# Fastest way to aggregate two typed arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, aggregation, typed-arrays

Hello everyone I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to aggregate two typed arrays into a single array.

Imagine data looks like this [Int8Array, Int8Array]

and I want to end up with a single

Int8Array

Currently i'm trying to loop through the parent array and through the subarray since the typed arrays do not support concat method I can't do my normal reduce and concat way.

```
  for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
     for (var n = 0, len = input[i].length; n < len; n++) {
       output.push(input[i][n]);
     }
  }
```

But i just feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this.

Attempting to use the set method it appears to be faster but not applicable to more than 2.

http://jsperf.com/typed-array-aggregation

Comment: is it two arrays (like you wrote) or is it a 2d array (as in your code)?

Comment: Take a look at this jsperf, attempting to set more than 2 typedarrays into a single array fails. 

http://jsperf.com/typed-array-aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following link. [How can I merge TypedArrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071463/how-can-i-merge-typedarrays-in-javascript)

They use the set method which does not require to use a loop

Comment: Using the set method appears to be the fastest in chrome and safari, however in firefox using 2 loops is a little faster than that.

http://jsperf.com/typed-array-aggregation

My only concern is the set method seems great for adding 2 into a single array, but I attempted and failed at making a loop that would properly set an output array with an input array containing more than 2 subarrays. 

[Int8,Int8] works great
[Int8,Int8,Int8,Int8] does not

Comment: Managed to get it working even with multiple arrays and it appears to be the fastest method across the board thus far

Answer (score 0):

**DISREGARD FOR TYPED ARRAYS**

You could `concatenate` the arrays like so:

```
var arr1 = ['1','2','3'];
var arr2 = ['a','b','c'];
var concatArr = arr1.concat(arr2);

//result: ['1','2','3','a','b','c']
```

From Mozilla's website: [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) of TypedArrays, the API doesn't provide a `concat` method like normal arrays.    

If the OP is using a standard array and managing the types manually then `concat` would be the answer.  It's hard to tell because TypedArrays don't have a `push` method either, so I'm not sure which he is using.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Of course, you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

To complete this task you have to go through loop. But here you can check out some other ways.

[Merge keys array and values array into an object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117916/merge-keys-array-and-values-array-into-an-object-in-javascript)

[merge two arrays (keys and values) into an object [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921962/merge-two-arrays-keys-and-values-into-an-object)